# Flicker while using layoutIfNeeded on containerview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, storyboard

I have a controller in storyboard that consist of two container views. I set the vertical distance between the two containers to zero.

What I want is to change the height constraint of one of the container at run time.

Here is the code for changing the constraint:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration animations:^{
    self.offeringContainerHeightConstraint.constant = [SJDataManager shared].offeringItems.count * kOfferingCellHeight + kOfferingHeaderHeight;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

The issue is, the other container view moves before so there is blank area between the two containers until the animation completes.

I want that two container views should change their constraint value in synchronisation so that this flicker can be removed.

Comment: I think (but I am not sure) the animateWithDuration is executed on a background thread, while layoutIfNeeded should be executed on the main thread. What happens if you encapsulate it like this dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[self.view layoutIfNeeded]; });

Comment: It makes the entire animation to occur at once that looks very bad.

Comment: I thought that is your intention sorry. But did the flicker disappear at least?

Comment: Yes flicker disappears but what I want is the animation without the flicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the solution for this. Actually it was the difference between the expectedHeightForRowAtIndexPath and heightForRowAtIndexPath. As the height returned by these two methods are different that is why I am getting the flicker.